# Android Asynctask addheader

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am trying to connect with my webservice restful to login a user.

i do that:

```
  private class LoginTask extends AsyncTask {
       OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        String base64NamePass;

        public LoginTask(String base64NamePass){
            this.base64NamePass = base64NamePass;
        }
        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
            Response response = null;
            try {
               response =  get("http://192.168.0.27:8080/ServicioRestTFG/rest/UsuariosServicesRs/login", base64NamePass);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return response;
        }

        private Response get (String url, String base64NamePass) throws IOException {
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .get()
                    .url(url)
                    .addHeader("Authorization", base64NamePass)
                    .build();
            return client.newCall(request).execute();
        }
    }
```

First i encoded the user and the pass with base64 and then i send it to my server.

But when i add the header:

```
Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .get()
                        .url(url)
                        .addHeader("Authorization", base64NamePass)
                        .build();
                return client.newCall(request).execute();
```

the app forceclosed and it doesnt show me what is the error, only close.

Any idea?

thanks

Comment: Did you check the logcat?